# How to Customize Cucumber reports with Boostrap css?

Tags: cucumber

I have tried to customize cucumber reports but I am not getting a clear picture of where to change the CSS according to our needs. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the custom CSS anywhere (best to keep in /support along with your formatter.rb), and then build the HTML page using cucumber's HTML builder referencing your CSS or you could have a pre-built HTML template and use it with the builder. Have a look at https://github.com/raldred/cucumber_textmate/ to get a general idea.